# How to show cumulative variance chart with multiple charts in r?

Tags: r, bar-chart, pca

So I have to show up to 95% cumulative variance however I don't see 95% cumulative variance till up to comp 132 which means my visualization chart doesn't show the data very well.

My code looks like this

```
PCA_Model_Input_Dataset <- PCA(Input_dataset, scale.unit = FALSE, ncp = 50, graph = TRUE)
print(PCA_Model_Input_Dataset$eig)
fviz_eig(PCA_Model_Input_Dataset, addlabels = TRUE, ncp =132, ylim = c(0, 50))

comp 125   0.59537285            0.056550043                          94.69613
comp 126   0.59007168            0.056046524                          94.75217
comp 127   0.58069413            0.055155820                          94.80733
comp 128   0.57387421            0.054508047                          94.86184
comp 129   0.57083252            0.054219139                          94.91605
comp 130   0.56803710            0.053953623                          94.97001
comp 131   0.55795953            0.052996429                          95.02300
comp 132   0.55090667            0.052326530                          95.07533
```

My chart looks like this
[image]

If I could split this chart in to multiple charts to better display my visualization results would be perfect.

Comment: Where is the issue?

Comment: I would do PCs 1:10 and other (>10).

Comment: @user2974951 the bar chart does not show good visualization of the data

Comment: Good visualisation of the data is very subjective. Putting 195 elements on the axis and 90% of them showing almost the same is also not a very good visualisation.

Comment: @EdwardMuldrew I can see that it's not a good graph. But what is your goal? What do you want to show? What do you want to omit?